# How to set flow layout?

Tags: java, swing

hi  i am trying to make java desktop application where i am trying to make jbutton  bottom left  i did following code  i dont know where i  am wrong my code is note working

here is my code

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;

new complete code 

    public class ApplicationCloseExample
    {   
        private JButton[] buttons;
        private void displayGUI()
        {
            final JFrame frame = new JFrame("Application Close Example");





            JPanel bottomPanel = new JPanel();
            bottomPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT, 5, 5));
              for (int i = 5; i < 8; i++) {
                 buttons[i] = new JButton(Integer.toString(i));
                    bottomPanel.add(buttons[i]);
              }

           // JButton button = new JButton("Comment");
           // bottomPanel.add(button);

        //    frame.getContentPane().add(contentPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
            frame.getContentPane().add(bottomPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

            frame.pack();
            frame.setVisible(true);
        }

        public static void main(String... args)
        {
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
            {
                public void run()
                {
                    new ApplicationCloseExample().displayGUI();
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

How can i achieve this

Comment: What exactly isn't working about your code? The only thing I could guess at is that the buttons array isn't initialised properly.

Comment: throwing  exception null pointer

Comment: and i initilised array like this private jButton[] buttons;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to assume the null pointer exception is something to do with your buttons array. Check that you have initialised it properly.

```
private JButton[] buttons = new JButton[8];
```

I copied your code into a test project and ran it after some modifications:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    final JFrame frame = new JFrame("Application Close Example");

    JPanel bottomPanel = new JPanel();
    bottomPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT, 5, 5));
      for (int i = 5; i < 8; i++) {
         buttons[i] = new JButton(Integer.toString(i));
            bottomPanel.add(buttons[i]);
      }

    frame.getContentPane().add(bottomPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

This produced a frame with three buttons aligned to the bottom left of the window.

Comment: Updated my answer. I believe it's your JButton array.

Answer (score 0):

There is an elegant solution that I'll give you but maybe it serves. Use WindowsBuilder and adds several buttons and then you look like is placing code. So make yourself an idea of the pattern that follows a setLayout with Flow.